# ReflectionTestUtils.setField (Mockito), not recognizing field.

Tags: java, spring

I am trying to test a Spring Boot Controller by using Mockito. I am following this tutorial: https://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/07/getting-started-with-springs-mvc-test-framework-part-1.html

The method I am testing is:

```
public class DigipostSpringConnector {

@Autowired
private String statusQueryToken;

@RequestMapping("/onCompletion")
public String whenSigningComplete(@RequestParam("status_query_token") String token){
    this.statusQueryToken = token;
}
```

So far, I have written this in my test-class:

```
public class DigipostSpringConnectorTest {

@Before
public void whenSigningCompleteSetsToken() throws Exception{
    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
    DigipostSpringConnector instance = new DigipostSpringConnector();
    ReflectionTestUtils.setField(instance, "statusQueryToken", statusQueryToken);

 }
}
```

However, I get the error "Cannot resolve symbol statusQueryToken", It seems like the test does not know that I am referring to the private field statusQueryToken, which is in another class.

Any ideas on how to solve this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is because value variable statusQueryToken in whenSigningCompleteSetsToken() method is not defined. Try this:

```
String statusQueryToken = "statusQueryToken"; 
ReflectionTestUtils.setField(instance, "statusQueryToken", statusQueryToken);
```

Answer (score 1):

`statusQueryToken` is undefined, simply because you haven't defined it. The third parameter to [`setField()`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/test/util/ReflectionTestUtils.html#setField-java.lang.Class-java.lang.String-java.lang.Object-) defines which value you want to assign to the field. So, you should do something like:

```
ReflectionTestUtils.setField(instance, "statusQueryToken", "the string value to set");
```

Replace `"the string value to set"` with whatever you want to assign to the field.

`ReflectionTestUtils` will then, with the help of [reflection](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/), search in `instance` for a field called `statusQueryToken`, and assign the value `"the string value to set"` to it.